# How to listen 2 ports in nginx?

Tags: nginx

I want to listen to ports with nginx and set the proxy.

here is the conf of the server

```
server{
    listen 8080;
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:82;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection keep-live;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }
}

server{
    listen 8081;
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:83;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection keep-live;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }
}
```

the 8080 is ok but the 8081 can not be connected

Comment: If you just want to map 8080 to 82 and 8081 to 83 it will be much simpler to do it with IPtables - otherwise you will have to assign domain name(s) to the different `server` sections (e.g. `server_name one.test.com;` and `server_name two.test.com`) and map those domain names to the IP address of the nginX server.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The sample might help you. I think this is a duplicate of [Nginx multiple ports](https://serverfault.com/questions/655067/is-it-possible-to-make-nginx-listen-to-different-ports)

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen 8000;
    server_name example.org;
    root /var/www/;
}
```

Comment: Thank you @Mir but I am using it for directing I do not want to give the root variable